# Android camera.action.CROP

Tags: android, image, crop

I want to crop an image selected from gallery .
My application picks image from gallery successfully but problem starts where user wants to crop the image  :

**Cropping image process :**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwDHs.png

*sorry i couldn't post images because of low reputation ;)

As shown in picture , if user select head of android logo , the output image from my application will be this image :

**RESULT :**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXWFF.jpg

I use this code to crop images :

```
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");   
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0); // This sets the max width.
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0); // This sets the max height.
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, REQUEST_TO_CROP);
```

As you can see in my code output image's width and height are set to 256 , 256 and i didn't set any aspect ratio for output image because i really don't know what user wants to crop .

My output image is not like selected area in original image at all and this is because my output image has fixed width and height and aspect ratio .

How can i set my output images height and width according selected area by user while cropping image ???

Comment: Hi I have used same like your code and that is working fine.. What is the exactly you got ?

Comment: My Code works correct too . the problem is with output image quality and aspect ratio

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`: https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html There are [many image cropping libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) -- please use one.

Comment: So i should look for cropping libraries ? Thank you ;)

Comment: Your result looks reasonable, you're selecting a larger area of the origin picture and saying it should be output square 256x256